# Wordpress functions.php gives an illegal string offset error for the page_back_ground_image custom field

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, frontend

I am working on a wordpress website with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and in relation to the code below (functions.php) I receive this error message on the Front End side of the website. Could you please give me some help?

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in C:\wamp6456\www\fictional-university\wp-content\themes\fictional-university-theme\functions.php on line 15
Warning: Illegal string offset 'pageBanner' in C:\wamp6456\www\fictional-university\wp-content\themes\fictional-university-theme\functions.php on line 15

Code (functions.php)

```html
<?php

function pageBanner($args = NULL) {
  
  if (!$args['title']) {
    $args['title'] = get_the_title();
  }

  if (!$args['subtitle']) {
    $args['subtitle'] = get_field('page_banner_subtitle');
  }

  if (!$args['photo']) {
    if (get_field('page_banner_background_image')) {
      $args['photo'] = get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['pageBanner'];
    } else {
      $args['photo'] = get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg');
    }
  }

  ?>
  <div class="page-banner">
    <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $args['photo']; ?>);"></div>
    <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
      <h1 class="page-banner__title"><?php echo $args['title'] ?></h1>
      <div class="page-banner__intro">
        <p><?php echo $args['subtitle']; ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
<?php }

function university_files() {
  wp_enqueue_script('googleMap', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBh9b1rNCp6kOi5JeMHiRP4klDymBeoEWk', NULL, '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('main-university-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i');
  wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('university_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'university_files');

function university_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  add_image_size('professorLandscape', 400, 260, true);
  add_image_size('professorPortrait', 480, 650, true);
  add_image_size('pageBanner', 1500, 350, true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'university_features');

function university_adjust_queries($query) {
  if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('program') AND is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'title');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
  }

  if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('event') AND is_main_query()) {
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
              array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'numeric'
              )
            ));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'university_adjust_queries');

function universityMapKey($api) {
  $api['key'] = 'AIzaSyCebykgkcMOnqg4KgonLWuJ2IUgG0S2xG4';
  return $api;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'universityMapKey');
```

Comment: The error is on this line of code:  $args['photo'] = get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['pageBanner'];

Comment: `var_dump(get_field('page_banner_background_image'));`?

Comment: this function returns string hence it's impossible to get array element from string by key

Comment: I solved it with this: if (!$args['photo']) {
    if (get_field('page_banner_background_image') && isset(get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']) && isset(get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['pageBanner'])) {
      $args['photo'] = get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['pageBanner'] ?? $args['photo'] = get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg');
    } else {
      $args['photo'] = get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg');
    }
  }

Comment: Great!!! This has the same result: `if (!$args['photo']) {
  $args['photo'] = get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['pageBanner'] ?? get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg');
}`